# Space before full stop or period

Tags: пунктуация

I've noticed some Russia users use a space before a full stop / period when writing English sentences.

Has this something to do with the Russian orthography?

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: Seems to happen with older people or folks used to write on a typewriter. There is no such rule in the language, it's not French!

Comment: There is a rule, a goverment standart (GOST) for typewriting (and blueprints). And it states that no space before comma or period allowed, and there must be one space (or new line) after them.

Comment: @OlegLobachev - oh? The French have a space before the full stop?

Comment: @RussellEngland French has spaces either side of several punctuation symbols, but not full stops.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no such syntax. What you're seeing are either people who don't know the rules (who are probably the same people who use “)))” instead of actual emoticons) or the people who use badly configured on-screen keyboards on their smartphones.